# Test transaction management in TokuMX

Tags: tokumx

I am new to TokuMX.
Since TokuMX supports transaction managament , I want to test the same.
How to test it? Is there any use case/ sample code to test the same?

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TokuMX's transactional semantics, including multi-statement transactions, are documented [here](http://docs.tokutek.com/tokumx/tokumx-transactions.html) and [here](http://docs.tokutek.com/tokumx/tokumx-commands.html#tokumx-new-commands-transactions), and there are more examples in this [blog post](http://www.tokutek.com/2013/10/introducing-tokumx-transactions-for-mongodb-applications/).